# Faster way to do Data Migration from SQL Server to MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, mongodb, database-migration

I am migrating the data on the SQL Server to my MongoDB through my API
in C#. I want to get the data from the DB and go through each row and
select and add required changes before inserting the collection to
MongoDB. I have an Admin Panel view which shows the live progress bar
with SignalR implemented which will show the task status.

What I want to know is which would be the faster method to do this. Getting the whole data through single call from the DB or getting the count of the records and iterate and get the record on the nth position from DB and insert?

Can anyone tell me the efficient and right  approach to this?

Also this function is done in after a interval of days or months and the data will grow as time passes in the SQL Server.

Comment: Re your two options: why not choose the third option of using `SqlDataReader` to stream the data from the database row-by-row? On the Mongo side, I'd suggest batching the inserts. It also depends on what "select and add required changes" means as to what would be more efficient overall.

Comment: I am using stored procedure to fetch data which has joins and functions to be done before retrieving it from SQL does that make any difference ? @Llama

Comment: Without concrete details, it's impossible to say what is most efficient. You have to work out for yourself what will involve the least operations/without exceeding memory limitations.